URL reuse under a Firebase project
Under a given Firebase project here is what I did:
Register a web app with a nickname: SOF-One
Firebase Hosting site: sof-one.web.app

Register a web app with a nickname: SOF-Two
Firebase Hosting site: sof-two.web.app

Register a web app with a nickname: SOF-Three
Firebase Hosting site: sof-three.web.app

The Project ID is unique looking something like:
abcusdx-kg626
The Project number is looking something like:
1012434920772

Each App ID is different and looks something like:
1:1017984180552:web:06a0123febbf49b0d247bb
Skipping the details I made the 3 demo sites accessible through the URLs below:
https://sof-one.web.app
https://sof-two.web.app
https://sof-three.web.app

Here the domains sof-one.web.app, sof-two.web.app and sof-three.web.app have obviously nothing to do with the Project ID.
The question that I would like to raise here is:
Can I get rid of one of the sites (i.e. URL) above and reuse it in some other project ?
In other words, for example, if I no longer need the address https://sof-two.web.app under this project. Can I remove the app SOF-Two from the project and then have the domain sof-two.web.app available for using in another project ?
If YES how can it be done ?
This post is in fact a reformulation of another one raising a problem that I faced when dealing with a project of mine:
Setting a hosting site in a firebase project

@Doug. I just tried again a few minutes ago. Even after a few days I still can't use the name I was previously using in my other project. This is unfortunate, but I may never be able to use it again (as Frank wrote) or it may take a much longer time. In any case I think this is too bad and I see no good reason for that.

When did I say "it's more possible than before"?
This question is a clearer reformulation of the the last one.
One can read both to see which is clearer for him or for her.
